# Changing the Default tab in Navigation drawer page tab sliding strip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

i have downloaded this project

https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip

in which there is navigation drawer and tab navigation together. when the program starts the first tab is the one in left, but i want the first tab to be the right one. any one knows how to do that?